# Power Automate HTTP error - {\"ErrorCode\":\"Forbidden\",\"Message\"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I'm creating a flow to reboot a user using the Microsoft Graph API. Everything seems to be checking out but I'm receiving this error message saying "unauthorized access". I granted consent to the graph API when registering the app but I'm still receiving the error. Any ideas on a solution?

The Uri is [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{DeviceID}/rebootNow](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/%7BDeviceID%7D/rebootNow)

---

Updated Question information -

DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All

Delegated

Perform user-impacting remote actions on Microsoft Intune devices

Authenticating using Active Directory OAuth.

Comment: Please update your question with all the parameters you are using in the HTTP Request action. Also is important to know what kind of access you granted to the app, because there are multiple options, starting by the top categories Delegated or Application permissions, then the specific service permissions.

Comment: +1 Please include which permissions you've granted to the application, and how you are obtaining an access token to call Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. I didn't have the correct access token. Thank you for the help